# Why you should not use Observable.create

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I've seen in many Rxjava tutorials , the usage of `Observable.create` method to create an Observable is not encouraged. Instead better to use `Observable.fromCallable` or `Observable.just` to emit a single object. Use `Observable.create` as a last option. Why is that? One of the problems is handling of back pressure. Is there any other risks by using `create`? Can anyone please explain it with some examples for better understanding? I didn't get a proper explanation for this question from any of the tutorials , that's why I'm asking here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the original [deprecation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/CHANGES.md#deprecation-of-createonsubscribe) notes?

Comment: I read, but did not understand properly. _**Unfortunately, guides, blogs, StackOverflow answers and mere typical user behavior still leads to this create method and lots of confusion, unstoppable sequences and MissingBackpressureException Therefore, as of 1.2.7 the create() method is now deprecated**_  Which means as of latest RxJava 2.X we are no more recommended to use it?

Comment: If so, which is the alternative , that bridges the reactive world with the callback-style world

Comment: The two argument `create` is usable for such bridges as it provides safeguards. However, many used the old create to implement sources, such as `just` and `from(Iterable)` over again.

Comment: I still use `create` to create an Observable from my existing asynchronous code. And I believe its the only way to do it. Isn't it?

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc? [1.x](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#create-rx.functions.Action1-rx.Emitter.BackpressureMode-) & [2.x](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#create-io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe-).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Swing/blob/master/src/main/java/hu/akarnokd/rxjava2/swing/ActionEventObservable.java) is an example for a bridge that doesn't use `create`.

Answer (score 0):

Is not about encourage, is about if `create` operator adjust of what you need.
The `create` operator give you the option to implement `onNext` or `onError`

```
   @Test
    public void testCreateObservableNext() {
        Observable.create(observer -> {
            observer.onNext("Injected value on Next");
            observer.onError(new NullPointerException("This is the final exception"));

    }).map(s -> ((String) s).toUpperCase())
            .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);
}
```

If you dont need that, `just` or `fromCallable` is just fine.

You can see examples of create operator here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/creating/ObservableCreate.java